# Why is the performance of Neo4j new index system with cypher drastically worse than specifying a starting point?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following versions of the same conceptual query:

i)

```
START a=node(1) MATCH (a)<-[:R]-(:B)<-[:S]-(:C)<-[:T]-(:D)<-[:U]-(e:E)
WHERE e.Property = "Value" WITH e SKIP 20 LIMIT 20 RETURN e ORDER BY e.Id;
```

ii)

```
MATCH (a:A { Id: 1}) WITH a MATCH (a)<-[:R]-(:B)<-[:S]-(:C)<-[:T]-(:D)
<-[:U]-(e:E) WHERE e.Property = "Value" WITH e SKIP 20 LIMIT 20 RETURN e ORDER BY e.Id;
```

iii)

```
MATCH (a:A {Id : 1})<-[:R]-(:B)<-[:S]-(:C)<-[:T]-(:D)<-[:U]-(e:E)
WHERE e.Property = "Value" WITH e SKIP 20 LIMIT 20 RETURN e ORDER BY e.Id;
```

I have also created an index for A on Id: `CREATE INDEX ON :A(Id)`

The total number of nodes is in the range of hundreds of thousands to two million. The relationship, and nodes on this system basically creates isolated trees at the root level (node a of type A in this example).

If I run query i) I get responses in the range of 31 ms to 100 ms.

If I run query ii) I may get responses between 1500 ms to 10000 ms (the max response time is achieved before the system lazy loads nodes into memory).

If I run query iii) I get a timeout through the web interface.

It is obvious that by skipping the indexing system (node(1) vs matching and getting the node) I should expect faster responses, but by an order of magnitude?

Also, if I only do `MATCH (a:A {Id: 1}) RETURN a;` I may get responses of 16 ms which are very close or virtually identical than just specifying a start point.

Hinting the system with `USING INDEX` does nothing to the performance.

Is my Cypher query wrong?

Comment: What version are you using? If you haven't update to 2.0.0 final and rerun your tests and report back.

Comment: I don't think those queries are conceptually the same, and they wouldn't be expected to perform similarly. The first query uses database id, (c.f. `ID(a)`), the other two use a property you've called "Id". The first gets exactly one node (ostensive/material/individual/reference) by pointer to disk, the other two get one or more nodes from an index (intensive/formal/common/sense).

Comment: @MichaelHunger thanks, it's now a totally no issue. I was using 2.0.0M3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was using Neo4j 2.0.0M3.

The problem was solved by installing 2.0.0 final.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

MATCH (a:A {Id : 1})<-[:R]-(:B)<-[:S]-(:C)<-[:T]-(:D)<-[:U]-(e:E {property="Value"})
WITH e SKIP 20 LIMIT 20 RETURN e ORDER BY e.Id;

I believe that's the new way of doing it since 2.0...

Rik

Comment: On M3 it was the same performance. For 2.0.0 the problem was already solved.